# Processing parameterized class and its sub classes in Scala

Tags: scala, types, template-specialization, specialization

I have a parameterized base class TBase, and two subclasses that inherits from it: TInt and TSeq.

```
abstract class TBase[T](val name:String)
{
    def encode(value:T) : Array[Byte]
    def decode(byteArray: Array[Byte]) : T
    def check(value:T) : Boolean
}

class TInt extends TBase[Int]("int")
{
    override def encode(value: Int) = {
        Array[Byte](value.toByte, value.toByte, value.toByte)
    }
    override def decode(byteArray: Array[Byte]) : Int = {
         byteArray.size   
    }
    override def check(value:Int) : Boolean = {
        if (value > 0) true
        else false
    }
}

class TSeq extends TBase[Seq[Int]]("seq")
{
    override def encode(value: Seq[Int]) = {
        Array[Byte](value.toByte, value.toByte, value.toByte)
    }
    override def decode(byteArray: Array[Byte]) : Seq[Int] = {
        Array[Int]()
    }
    override def check(value:Seq[Int]) : Boolean = {
        true
    }
}
```

I need to iterate over the instances of TBase or its subclasses. This is what I tried.

```
object Main extends App {
    val a = Array[TBase[Any]](new TInt, new TSeq) <--
    a.foreach {i => 
        println(i.decode(Array[Byte]()))
    }
}
```

I got error messages.

```
error: kinds of the type arguments (this.TBase) do not conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type T).
this.TBase's type parameters do not match type T's expected parameters:
class TBase has one type parameter, but type T has none
    val a = Array[TBase](new TInt, new TSeq)
                 ^
one error found
```

What might be wrong? Or, what is the proper way to invoke methods in subclasses with various type specialization?

#### EDIT

I tried `abstract class TBase[+T <: Any](val name:String)` with `val a = Array[TBase[Any]]` to get those errors.

```
T vs Any/16-3. inheritance.scala:3: error: covariant type T occurs in contravariant position in type T of value value
    def encode(value:T) : Array[Byte]
               ^
T vs Any/16-3. inheritance.scala:5: error: covariant type T occurs in contravariant position in type T of value value
    def check(value:T) : Boolean
              ^
two errors found
```

Comment: You asked one question ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293284/type-parameter-vs-any-in-scala/36293599)), which I answered, then you asked this one, which I answered, then you edited it to ask something completely different. Can you please work on your problem for a couple of hours and come back if you get really stuck instead of incrementally pasting each new error message one by one as they appear? :) Also, don't edit questions like that after they have been answered, perhaps someone else will have the same problem as you did. Have a new problem - post a new question.

Comment: @slouc: I revised the question to clarify what my original question, and what I have tried. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Editing can lead to confusion. Always edit so that you add the part in the "edit" section after the question and never mess around with the original text. But ok, never mind that. Is all good now? Do you need your type to be covariant (that is, do you want to resolve the "covariant type in contravariant position" error too?)

Comment: @slouc: I solved the current issue with your help now, but it would be also great to know what is the problem of the covariant error.

Comment: If a class is covariant in its type T (declared as +T) then this type can only be used in covariant position, that is, as a return value type. You are using it as a parameter type in methods encode and check. Variance is a tricky business and it's hard to explain it in one comment; if you need a more detailed explanation, take a look at [my blog post](https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/variance-in-java-and-scala-63af925d21dc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare higher kinded types with an existential type:

```
val a = Array[TBase[_]](new TInt, new TSeq)
```